# How to change a list URL via JSOM?

Tags: client-object-model

I'm trying to make a JSOM utility that will allow me to alter the properties of pre-existing document libraries. So far I have successfully managed to update the list 'Title' and 'Description' properties.

The bit I am stuck on is how can I update the URL for the list to a value of my choosing?

I have had a look already at this MSDN advice on the [List Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245826.aspx/). There are no pre-existing methods that I can use to update the URL.

Is there a way of doing this in JSOM in SharePoint or have I hit a dead end? Any help would be very much appreciated.

My code so far is as follows:

```
// Get the current context
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
// Get the current site (SPWeb) 
var web = context.get_web(); 
// Get the library 
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(ExDocLibName);

//Update some properties of the library
list.set_description('Updated Library description')
list.set_title(NewDocLibName)
list.update();

context.load(list)

// Create callback handlers
var success = Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess); 
var failure = Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailure); 

// Execute an async query
context.executeQueryAsync(success,failure);

    }
// Async query succeeded.
function onSuccess(sender, args) {

alert('library details have been updated');

// Refresh the page.
SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
}

// Async query failed.
function onFailure(sender, args) {
alert(args.get_message());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL of `SPList` object is read only property. And you can't set a new URL to it.

The best option you can have is to delete the existing list and create a new one.

Comment: Not even possible from server side object model, let alone the client side.